# C# linq get subset of datatable from datatable starting from specified ordinal position

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I would like to take an existing DataTable and create a subset of the DataTable by taking all columns from a specified ordinal position (where the DataTable is passed to my method.

I saw a similar post, but want all data in each row.

I am attempting to do something along the lines of the following code snippet where nDataTableColWriteStart could be 0 (i.e. take all columns), 1 (i.e. start from the Ordinal position 1), etc.

The list of DataColumns is correct, but I cannot seem to get the sub-DataTable to only have those columns.

Thanks,

```
        List<DataColumn> dataColumns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.Ordinal >= nDataTableColWriteStart).ToList();
        DataTable subTable = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(w => dataColumns.Select(c => w[c]).Any()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code, you are selecting all rows that have all the required columns (which would be all rows), but then you add each row - as is with all columns - to a new data table.

If you don't want to mutate the original DataTable, you have to do one of the following:
Option 1:
- Create a new DataTable,
- For each column you need from the source table, create a new column in the destination table, manually copy all properties
- create a new row in the destination table for each row in the source table, and add the new row to the destination table

Option 2:
Copy the DataTable, remove the columns you don't need:

```
var subTable = dt.Copy();
for (var i = 0; i < nDataTableColWriteStart; i++)
   subTable.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

If you can remove columns from the source table directly, then you don't need to copy the datatable, just remove the columns.

If you insist on using linq, you could use

```
Enumerable.Range(0, nDataTableColWriteStart).ToList().ForEach(i => subTable.Columns.RemoveAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this, but it is not completely using Linq.

```
        // get the list of columns to remove
        List<DataColumn> dataColumnsToRemove = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.Ordinal < nDataTableColWriteStart).ToList();

        // copy the DataTable
        DataTable dtSubset = dt.Copy();

        // remove unwanted columns
        foreach (DataColumn col in dataColumnsToRemove)
        {
            dtSubset.Columns.Remove(col.ColumnName);
        }
```